# Full Template Specialization errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, template-specialization

Since I am SIMD'ifying my code I decided to use template specialization to handle each type case but it seems I did something wrong.

```
template<typename T> struct __declspec(align(16)) TVec2
{
};

template<> __declspec(align(16)) struct TVec2<s64>
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            s64 x, y;
        };
        struct
        {
            __m128i v;
        };
    };
    TVec2()
    {
        v = _mm_setzero_si128();
    }
    TVec2(s64 scalar)
    {
        v = _mm_set_epi64x(scalar, scalar);
    }
    TVec2(s64 x, s64 y)
    {
        v = _mm_set_epi64x(x, y);
    }
    template<typename U> operator TVec2<U>() const
    {
        return TVec2<U>(static_cast<U>(x), static_cast<U>(y));
    }
    s64& operator[](word index)
    {
        return v.m128i_i64[index];
    }
    const s64& operator[](word index) const
    {
        return v.m128i_i64[index];
    }
};
// There are other specializations but they produce the same errors
```

When I compile in Visual Studio (2015) I get (C2988: unrecognizeable template declaration/definition) followed by (C2059: syntax error: "< end Parse >"). I am fairly sure I followed the documentation for specialization correctly but I am prone to errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is caused by __declspec written before structure keyword so template is not recognized properly. Try changing to

```
template<> struct __declspec(align(16)) TVec2<s64>
```

It may be also a good idea to use [alignas specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) and get rid of nameless struct/union.

Comment: Wow, that was a simple problem, thanks for spotting that.